# Mongoose validation fails for required fields even when I provide values for that fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following model:

```
/**
 * @module optikos
 */
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

/**
 * Define the schema of the main table(Document)
 * Needs to be redefined to add user role here
 */
const dbUri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/optikosmaindb';
mongoose.connect(dbUri,{ useNewUrlParser: true });
const optikosSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required:[true,'Email is required']
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required:[true,'Password is required']
    },
    dbpath: {
        type: String,
        required:true
    },
    role:{
        type:String,
        lowercase:true,
        enum:{
            values:['admin','employee','shop owner'],
            message:'`${VALUE} is not a valid role`'
        },
        default:'shop owner'
    },
    payment_status: {
        /***
         * Only show owners need to have a payment status
         */
        required:this.role == 'shop owner',
        type: String,
        lowercase:true,
        enum:{
            values:['pending','paid'],
            message:'`{VALUE} is not a valid payment status`'
        },
        default: 'pending' //will change to paid once a payment transaction is completed

    },
    payment_reset: {
        required:this.role == 'shop owner',
        type: Date,
        default:Date.now
    }
});

const Optikos = mongoose.model('optikos',optikosSchema);
module.exports = Optikos;
```

I have another file called `index.js` in which I require it like this to create some users for my database:

```
const admins = require('./admins');
const Optikos = require('../schemas/optikos');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
async function setup() {
    console.log('Setting app Optikos main database');

    try {

        let registeredAdmins = admins.map(async admin=>{
            let {email,name,password} = admin;
            let role = 'admin';
            let saltRounds = 10;
            password = await bcrypt.hash(password,saltRounds);

            let dbpath = dbUri;
            let user = new Optikos({
                'name':name,
                'email':email,
                'password':password,
                'role':role,
                'dbpath':dbpath
            });

            return user;
        });
        let response  = await Optikos.create(registeredAdmins);
        console.log('Registered admins')
        process.exit(0);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error error error')
        console.log(e)
        process.exit(1)
    }

}

setup();
```

The admins file is an array of objects containing a name,email and password fields.However after trying to run the `index`file I get the following: "{ ValidationError: optikos validation failed: dbpath: Path `dbpath` is required., password: Password is required, email: Email is required".However If I log all the variables that I am passing to "new Optikos()" I get the values that I expect.What is wrong?

Comment: I think registeredAdmins is returned empty; since here the map function will return an array of promises as it calls asynchronous functions and you have to wait for all promises to get the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the required fields error by doing this:

```
let registeredAdmins = admins.map(async admin=>{
            let {email,name,password} = admin;
            let role = 'admin';
            let saltRounds = 10;
            password = await bcrypt.hash(password,saltRounds);

            let dbpath = dbUri;
            let user = new Optikos({
                'name':name,
                'email':email,
                'password':password,
                'role':role,
                'dbpath':dbpath
            });

            return user;
        });
        Promise.all(registeredAdmins)
        .then(async users=>{
            console.log(users)
            await Optikos.create(users);
            console.log('Yeap')
        }).catch(e=>{
            console.log(e)
        })
```

Since registeredAdmins is a list of promises I use Promise.all() to get the values of the resolved promises.Thanks @AbdullahDibas for the hint

Answer (score 0):

It is usually due to the fact that `async await` doesn't work the expected way in the situations of looping often ( though another alternative for the same is `for-await-in`, but it is still not considered to be production safe, or a good practise by some of the eslint standards ) and so, you may wish to rephrase your code as :

```
const admins = require('./admins');
const Optikos = require('../schemas/optikos');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

async function setup() {
    console.log('Setting app Optikos main database');
    const passwordPromises = [];
    try {

        admins.forEach(admin => {
            let { password } = admin;
            let saltRounds = 10;
            passwordPromises.push(bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds));
        });

        const passwords = await Promise.all(passwordPromises);

        let registeredAdmins = admins.map((admin, index) => {
            let { email, name } = admin;
            let user = new Optikos({
                'name': name,
                'email': email,
                // The below would work because Promise.all resolves them in
                // the sequential order. Also, since there would be a one - to - one
                // mapping in the indices of the admins and the password due to the above stated fact
                // the following would work
                'password': passwords[index],
                'role': 'admin',
                'dbpath': dbUri
            });
            return user;
        });

        let response = await Optikos.create(registeredAdmins);
        console.log('Registered admins')
        process.exit(0);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error error error')
        console.log(e)
        process.exit(1)
    }

}
```